# No puedo recuperar un objeto de localstorage en angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

No consigo recuperar un objeto en el localstorage del navegador en angular. haciendo un console.log del objeto que quiero recuperar me sale NULL.

```
this.userservice.signup(this.user, true).subscribe(
      response =>
      {
        this.identity = response;
    //    this.username = this.identity['name'];
      //  this.usersurname = this.identity['surname'];
          console.log('identity',this.identity);
      //  console.log(this.user);
        // persistir datos usuario identificado
        localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
        localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));
    //    console.log('identity: ', JSON.parse(this.identity));
        // redireccion a inicio
        this.router.navigate(['inicio']);
      //  console.log(this.identity);

      }
```

el codigo de arriba es donde almaceno 'identity' luego en un servicio lo intento recuperar
user.service.ts

```
getIdentity()
  {


    let identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));
    console.log(this.identity);//este console.log es donde me sale null
    if(identity && identity != "undefined")
    {
      this.identity = identity;
    }
    else
    {
      this.identity = null;
    }

    return this.identity;
  }
```

he comprobado en el navegador que el objeto identity se guarda en el localstorage del chrome.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No estarías mirando `this.identity` antes de asignarlo?

Comment: no lo creo por que identity lo uso en otro componente para mostrar el nombre y el apellido del usuario logeado y no le llegan los datos

Comment: Lo que digo es que en `getIdentity` estás mirando `this.identity` antes de darle un valor. Muévelo justo antes del `return`.

Comment: Toda la razón, @ChemaCortes. Deberías hacer un `console.log(identity)`, no `console.log(this.identity)`, @Rafael.

Comment: teniais razon estaba poniendo mal el console.log. getIdentity() devulve el objeto pero en otro componente cuando hago en el html {{ identity.name + '' + identity.surname}} no me coge los valores de identity. el objeto son varios arrays unos vacios...